# Django post request failing silently

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django - React project. I am having an issue where one of my post APIs is throwing an error message which I am not being able to resolve.

Following is the class from my views.py

```
class OrdersList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrderSerializer
```

Following is the urls.py

```
path('orders/', views.OrdersList.as_view()),
```

Following is the post call from react.js

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('customer_id', customerId);
axios.post(createOrderUrlRef.current, formData).then((response) => {
     console.log(`${TAG} ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log(`${TAG} error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
});
```

My environment is currently DEBUG and I see following error in console of Firefox,

```
OrderConfirmation error: {"message":"Request aborted","name":"AxiosError","stack":"AxiosError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:88555:18\nhandleAbort@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87934:14\..."headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"post","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/","data":{}},"code":"ECONNABORTED","status":null}
```

There is no error message seen in django console.

Comment: Are there any other fields the Django model accepts? Is `customer_id` the only field?